# How to get data from the local DB of Android 4 broken phone

Tags: android, android-sqlite

How to get data from the local DB of Android phone with a broken display. I can see the screen and work somehow.

Comment: what is the relation between screen and DB

Comment: @edwin I want to migrate my app data to another phone